# Why do clang and gcc disagree on this virtual inheritance code?

Tags: c++, c++11, g++, clang++

I'm seeing some differences in how clang 3.8.0 and gcc 6.2.1 handle what I believe to be valid code. Here's an example, which `clang++ --std=c++11 vitest.cpp` compiles without comment:

```
#include <iostream>

class Processor {
public:
    Processor( int i, float f ) {}

    virtual ~Processor() noexcept {}

    virtual void getStatistics() = 0;
};

class PageProvider : virtual public Processor {
public:
    PageProvider( int i, float f )
//      : Processor{i,f}    // Without this, GCC wants to call default ctor
    {}

    virtual ~PageProvider() {}
};

class QuotePageProvider : public PageProvider {
public:
    QuotePageProvider( int i, float f )
        : Processor{i,f},
            PageProvider{i,f}
    {}

    virtual void getStatistics() { std::cout << "Hi there" << std::endl; };
};

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    PageProvider*   prov2{new QuotePageProvider{1,2.2}};
    prov2->getStatistics();
    delete prov2;
}
```

The first anomaly is that g++ (with the same command-line arguments) complains about the PageProvider constructor:

```
vitest.cpp:16:2: error: no matching function for call to ‘Processor::Processor()’
```

This can be gotten around by uncommenting the explicit initialization of Processor as shown above. According to [aschepler's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40431913/1440841) below, this is a known gcc bug.

Having dispensed with that, things get more interesting:

```
vitest.cpp: In constructor ‘QuotePageProvider::QuotePageProvider(int, float)’:
vitest.cpp:25:20: error: cannot allocate an object of abstract type ‘PageProvider’
    PageProvider{i,f}
                    ^
vitest.cpp:12:7: note:   because the following virtual functions are pure within ‘PageProvider’:
 class PageProvider : virtual public Processor {
       ^~~~~~~~~~~~
vitest.cpp:9:15: note:  virtual void Processor::getStatistics()
  virtual void getStatistics() = 0;
               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

It seems that gcc insists on having an implementation of getStatistics() available in `PageProvider` in order to compile `QuotePageProvider`, while clang does not. I get the same results compiling [with gcc 5.1](http://ideone.com/b5FLO9).

I can persuade gcc to compile the code by doing any of the following:

- Reducing the number of arguments to `PageProvider`'s constructor to 1
  (irrespective of type).
- Making `PageProvider`'s inheritance of `Processor` non-virtual.
- In the init-list of `QuotePageProvider`'s constructor, changing the initialization of `PageProvider` to use parentheses instead of curlies. A similar change to the initialization of `Processor` immediately above has no effect.

Is it possible that this is some weird corner-case in the standard that the two compilers have interpreted differently, or is one of them broken?

Comment: The second half is another GCC bug. (Well, it was a bug in the standard IIRC that got implemented to the letter, and then the standard got fixed, and then GCC got fixed, but not completely.)

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=65615

Comment: @T.C. bingo, that looks to be exactly it. If you want to upgrade your comments to an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 4):

This is gcc bug [53878](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=53878).

An abstract class should not need to construct its virtual base classes.

Comment: Thanks for the reference, but that seems to be just the first part of the problem. If PageProvider explicitly initializes Processor, that seems to work around the bug you cited, but there's still the issue that the compiler wants an implementation of getStatistics(). Or are you saying they're somehow related?